# TransactionScope does not Rollback when even when an exception is thrown

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

I making a few API calls inside the transaction block. From what I know if any of these APIs throw an exception then the transaction should rollback. By rollback I understand that all the tasks that the APIs that successfully executed did is undone. The problem is that even if an API throws an exception the scope.Complete() is reached and the rollback does not take place.

This is my transaction block. The method it is being called in does not have a try catch block

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    await UpdateAuditPlanL3Async(auditCalender);
    await SaveAuditManagementL3(auditMgmt);
    await SaveAuditManagementStdDetaiL3(mgmtStdDetails);
    await SaveAuditObservationDetailL3(obsdetail);
    scope.Complete();
}
```

The parameters to the awaited methods are lists

This below is a sample code to show the way i am calling the API

```
public async Task UpdateAuditPlanL3Async(AuditCalendarL3 auditCalendarl3)
{
    string url = string.Concat(GlobalDeclaration.APIServerUrl, "UpdateAuditPlanL3?AuditplanId=" + auditCalendarl3.AuditplanId + "&Token=" + GlobalDeclaration.ApiToken);
    url = GlobalDeclaration.CleanURL(url);
    var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(auditCalendarl3);
    var requestContent = new StringContent(myContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await Program.httpClient.PutAsync(url, requestContent);
    var responseCode = response.StatusCode;
    if (responseCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || responseCode == HttpStatusCode.Created || responseCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
    {
        GlobalDeclaration.log.Info("UpdateAuditPlanL3 API executed successfully. The response code is " + responseCode);
    }
    else
    {
        GlobalDeclaration.exlog.Error("UpdateAuditPlanL3 API failed. The response code is " + responseCode);
        throw new Exception("UpdateAuditPlanL3 API execution failed.");
    }
}
```

In my case the below API is throwing an exception. Now i know why the exception is being thrown. I want to know how can i solve the rollback not happening even when the exception is being thrown

```
private async Task SaveAuditObservationDetailL3(List<AuditObservationDetailL3> adobsdtl)
{
    string url = string.Concat(GlobalDeclaration.APIServerUrl, "SaveAuditObservationDetailL3?Token=" + GlobalDeclaration.ApiToken);
    url = GlobalDeclaration.CleanURL(url);
    var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(adobsdtl);
    var requestContent = new StringContent(myContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await Program.httpClient.PostAsync(url, requestContent);
    var responseCode = response.StatusCode;
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
    {
        GlobalDeclaration.log.Info("SaveAuditObservationDetailL3 API executed successfully. The response code is " + responseCode);
        MessageBox.Show("Observation Checkpoints created successfully.");
    }
    else
    {
        GlobalDeclaration.exlog.Error("SaveAuditObservationDetailL3 API failed. The response code is " + responseCode);
        throw new Exception("SaveAuditObservationDetailL3 API failed. The response code is " + responseCode);
    }
}
```

I have read on how to use transactionscope and everywhere it says that the rollback should occur. I also tried using a try catch block inside the transaction scope but to no avail. I even removed the TransactionScopeAsynFlowOption.Enabled and also tried the .Suppress but it always reaches the scope.Complete() even when an exception is thrown.

Comment: TransactionScope *does* roll back. There's no ADO.NET code in the question though, so it's unclear what is supposed to roll back

Comment: `By rollback I understand that all the tasks that the APIs that successfully executed did is undone.` wrong. For all practical purposes, only ADO.NET (database) operations executed inside the scope are rolled back. HTTP knows nothing about transactions. The WS-Transaction standard was available for SOAP services but setting this up to work required *very* tricky configuration *and* setting up intermediary services to act as transaction coordinators. And it just didn't scale at all.

Comment: what is the actual business scenario you want to implement? There are actual, tested solutions that don't require distributed transactions. The names of the operations suggest you only have a single set of tightly-related services sent to the same service. The easy solution in that case is to actually send a single POST or PUT with all the objects, eg as a JSON payload, and have the service handle the individual operations.

Comment: If we ignore all this for once then my main goal is to make multiple independent HTTP API calls inside a transaction. The API calls are similar to the one i showed above. Even if one API throws an exception then all of them should not work. Only when all of them are a success should the execution continue. Now I am not exactly sure how i should go about doing it. Like should i open the http client inside the transaction and then make the API calls? I tried using Promise.All but again to no avail.

Comment: `multiple independent HTTP API calls inside a transaction` That's a contradicting statement. If you want them in a "transaction" they're tightly dependent. HTTP has no concept of transactions anyway. So either you create your own protocol, or use a *single* request for all changes. Which, btw, is something supported by HTTP multipart requests.

Comment: `Only when all of them are a success should the execution continue` HTTP has no such concept. You'll have to explicitly orchestrate those operations and undo or reverse them if something goes wrong. This also means you need to keep track of each operation's progress. When you use TransactionScope with a database, it's the database that does all this, not the `BeginTransaction` or `new` calls. This is nothing new, there are a *lot* of books and articles on this over the last 20-30 years. That's why it's *a lot * easier to make changes in a *single* service call that multiple independent ones.

Comment: Thank you. i see where i am wrong and i think i understand what i should do.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that even if an API throws an exception the scope.Complete() is reached...

No, I  do not think that is what is happening here. A few more likely options:

1. no exception is being thrown
2. the exception is being swallowed (caught and not rethrown) by the individual method
3. an exception is thrown and the scope is rolled back, but the thing you want to rollback doesn't support ambient transactions (very few things do)
4. an exception is thrown and the scope is rolled back, and the thing you want to rollback *does* support ambient transactions, but the usage is not correct - for example, a `SqlConnection` must be opened *inside* the ambient transaction in order for it to support this usage

Given that you've shown some of the HTTP API code, I think we can rule out 2, and you seem confident that we can rule out 1, and you *have* enabled async flow in thr transaction (that was going to be my item zero), so that leaves 3 and 4; what is the thing that you are expecting to rollback? Can we see *that*, and how confident are you that it supports ambient transactions?

To be clear: random HTTP calls do not support transactions, ambient or explicit. Transactions require lots of coordination, requiring lots of logic and work *on both sides*; WCF offers some of this, for example; it may also require additional services such as DTC. Mostly, ambient transactions tend to be restricted to SQL work (on a subset of ADO.NET providers), because SQL databases at least usually have a *concept* of transactions; raw HTTP does not.

(side note: ambient transactions are *convenient*, but almost always a bad approach, although this is somewhat subjective, or at least contextual)

Comment: `WCF offers some of this, for example; it may also require additional services such as DTC.` that's a battleship-sized can of worms.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I strongly agree, hence my parenthetical footnote

Comment: To think that once we thought this was a good idea - I remember Clemens Vasters talking about whether 2 or 3 ACKs are needed at a Teched conf.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you make it sound like having a transaction (with all the associated blocking, etc) that spans multiple companies on different clouds / premises, in different continents, requiring multiple round-trips to co-ordinate: might have some inherent difficulties! have more faith!

Comment: I am saving records in the database as the name of the APIs may suggest. I am expecting it to rollback the saved records i.e. remove them after saving if the transaction fails. But as i am writing it down i too think this may actually not what rollback does.

Comment: @LavanyaTulsian I can't see any database code, so I can't comment much; but: if there's a HTTP call between your code and whatever is doing the database access: then that isn't going to work (unless there's something like WCF with transactions enabled in the mix); the database code would need to be in the same process, on the same async execution context (i.e. the same `await` path)

Comment: I have absolutely zero knowledge much less understanding of anything related to WCF. I do understand your point. Thank you

Comment: @LavanyaTulsian to be 100% clear, I am *absolutely not* saying "use WCF for this"; that approach re distributed transactions was briefly a thing... in 2006; it is very rarely considered a good approach now